# Wordpress: using a page as a "block" to call in the template

Tags: php, wordpress

Sometimes I need to insert in the template a "block" of text (and images) that must be editable by the clients from the backend (they're obviously not able to coding).
To solve I used to create a new Page in the backend and simply call it in the template with:

```
<?php
$block = get_page( $id ); 
echo '<h3>'. $block->post_title .'</h3>';
echo apply_filters('the_content', $block->post_content);
?>
```

Then, since that page is not a standard page that haven't to be displayable as single page, I set it to `Visibility=Private` and `no index` in the SEO plugin.

Is this a correct way to do what I need? Or is there a better one?
Let me know, thank

Comment: Do you want to display the contents of the page without it being visible to the public?

Comment: If only the admin or any other high level user is going to edit this page and if it doesn't need much styling then I would simply create a template file in the theme directory which will show up in "Wp Admin/Appearance/Editor" for editing...

Comment: @Llewellyn1411: Yes I want display contents without it being visible to the public but that's the final work, I asked about the whole thing.

Comment: @Jay Bhatt: the client needs to style the block with a WYSIWYG editor but with your solution (template file) I will have a standard single page. I want to call the content into other page templates.

Comment: @FredK It's all ready mentioned in the comment. "if it doesn't need much styling then".

Answer (score 1):

As with all things Wordpress, there are different ways to do it depending on how far you want to go in customizing your clients' experience. A simple way to solve this issue is to [turn that area of your template into an area that accepts widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes#Another_complete_example) and then add a [plugin that provides a widget that supports rich text editing](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/). Your clients can then simply edit the text and images through the widget interface.

It sounds like you're already editing template files, so the link above takes you directly to the code you'll need in functions.php and your template file. But if you need more background, also read the docs on [Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: Interesting, I'm thinking about your solution but: the block I have to call is not (always) to put in the sidebar (your first link explain how to register a sidebar widget). In second place, I have always to custom the block with the use of custom fields, is it possible?

Comment: They call it a "sidebar" but you can put it anywhere in your template. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Ok. for the 2nd question: I created the new widgetized area, now I want to add a widget in that area. But the widget must have a text area and some custom fields (such as checkboxes or radio buttons). To manage custom fields I use "Advanced custom fields" plugin but I think it can not add custom fields to a widget.

Comment: Ahh, I don't think the plugin I pointed you to has rich text editing support for forms and I'm not familiar with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.